# "error: array type has incomplete element type" after trying to pass two-dimensional array

Tags: c, gcc

newbie need help. This code works on Windows(Visual Studio 2012), but on GCC i get error: "array type has incomplete element type" for all void type functions below. Can someone tell me why ? (this is only a piece of my all code). 
**Thank you :-)**

```
void initialize_arrays(struct data data_list[][ARRAY_SIZE]);
void read_file(struct data data_list[][ARRAY_SIZE]);
void print_struct_array(struct data data_list[][ARRAY_SIZE]);
void parallel_print(int thread_number, struct data data_list[][ARRAY_SIZE]);
void print_struct(struct data data_struct, int thread, int array_num, int elem_num);

struct data {
    char *name;
    int age;
    double lenght;
};

int main()
{
    struct data data_array[STRUCT_SIZE][ARRAY_SIZE];
    initialize_arrays(data_array);
    read_file(data_array);
    print_struct_array(data_array);
    parallel_print(6, data_array);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void initialize_arrays(struct data data_list[][ARRAY_SIZE])
{
    int i,j;
    for(i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < STRUCT_SIZE; j++)
        {
            data_list[i][j].name = NULL;
            data_list[i][j].age = 0;
            data_list[i][j].lenght = 0.0;
        }
}
```

Comment: Move `struct data` definition to the beginning, before function prototypes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the point where the function prototypes are declared, there is no such thing as `struct data` known to the program, because the struct declaration appear further down.

Move the struct declaration above the function prototypes.

(Whether some C language code works or not in Visual Studio is one big lottery, since it barely follows any C standard.)